# Implement many_to_many relation with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I've just started Entity Framework programming.

I defined three classes in my program: User, Group and Permission. Each user can be a member of several groups. In each group, several user can be member. Each group can have multiple permissions, and A permission can be applied for several groups. Classes have been implemented as follows:

```
public class ClassUser
 {

....

 public virtual ICollection<ClassGroup> Groups { get; set; }

}

public class ClassPermission
 {

....

public virtual ICollection<ClassGroup> Groups { get; set; }

}

public class ClassGroup

{

....

public virtual ICollection<ClassUser> Users { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ClassPermission> Permissions { get; set;

}
```

how can implement optimized C# code for these queries:

How can I get list of all permissions that a user has?

How can I get list of all users that a have "Permission 1"?

Thanks!

Comment: Easy to do that. See [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [41787644](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787577/eager-load-many-to-many-ef-core/41787644)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question because that is EF Core. But i am sure this question has been asked many times before...