# Eager Load many to Many - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, asp.net-core

Hello I have a many to many relationship set up like following.

```
public class order
{
    public int id { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<OrderProducts> Products { get; set; }
}

public class product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderProducts> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderProducts
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order{ get; set; }

    public int ProductIdId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }   
}
```

I would like to Include (Eager load) all products into their orders, but when using same approach like shown with customer, my product list get populated with OrderProducts-objects and not Product-objects

```
public IEnumerable<Order> GetAll()
{
    return dataContext.Orders
                      .Include(order => order.Customer)
                      // now include all products aswell..
}
```

I have tried stuff like witout any luck

```
  .Include(order => order.Products.Where(op => op.OrderId == order.Id).Select(p => p.Product))
```

So would appreciate if someone could help me out here..
You'r also most welcome to share any good resources on how to construct more advanced lambdas, since i'm not that familiar with this yet..

Comment: why your `OrderProducts` class has only one `Product`? not an array or list

Comment: @S.Serp `OrderProducts` is a a many-to-many relation table, so it links a single order to a single product

Comment: Just to Clerify - Robin was right all along.. After reading this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6166 and doing some debugging the object was there all along.. I just needed to rearange my [JsonIgnore] attributes abit.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just use `ThenInclude()` statement:

```
public class order
{
    public int id { get; set; }    
    public virtual IList<OrderProducts> OrderProducts { get; set; }
}
//...
public IEnumerable<Order> GetAll()
{
    return dataContext.Orders
                      .Include(order => order.OrderProducts)
                      .ThenInclude(orderProducts => orderProducts.Product);
}
```

As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many), many-to-many relation is not yet implemented. You have to load your `OrderProducts` then `Select(orderProducts => orderProducts.Product)`

**Important:** IntelliSense completion might tell you can't do this, but you can, just make a real build and it will work

Comment: thx for the link. I have update my DbContext as shown, but the ThenInclude dosen't allow me to select products.?

Comment: does it make any difference to use IList instead of ICollection?
Thought i read somewhere when working with EF, one should always use collections?

Comment: `IList` or `ICollection` should work the same way (at least in this case). What's the problem exactly ?
Here's a full [example](https://imgur.com/a/L8Em7)

Comment: thx for example.. In my thenInclude(op => op.(no_Access) ) i dont get acces to my properties from the OrderProduct class.

Comment: You should have 2 possible methods for `ThenInclude()`: `ThenInclude(Expression<Func<IList<T>>>, object>>)` and `ThenInclude(Expression<Func<T>>, object>>)` (notice that one is the list, and the other is just an element) [example](https://imgur.com/a/GhT1z)

Comment: well getting closer but think im missing something...
If i add in an extra prop (y) i can acces the OrderProduct on my x prop like so - 
.Include(order=> order.Products).ThenInclude(x => y => x.CardMechanicId)
But this gives me an error however.. any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you returning a lamdba in the `ThenInclude()`? What is giving youy an error when just returning as I suggest? The compiler or your IDE? Did you try to build it anyway?

Comment: Please show what's your error

Comment: If I use the original answer i dont get any errors. Its like its ignoring the ThenInclude statement and returning my order-product as in my original question.

Comment: It WILL return OrderProduct, but the object inside will be available, so youy just have to `Select()` it to transform it to a product list, like in the sample I showed you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133736/discussion-between-user3116167-and-robin-thoni).

Comment: OK, but tomorrow, it's 3:30 AM in Canada :) Ping me so I don't forget about it

Comment: The 1/22 @ 7:00 comment above is important - intellisense makes it seem like you can't do .ThenInclude(orderProduct => orderProduct.Product), but it is in the second overload. May be worth stating in the answer as I totally missed this until reading the comments.

Comment: Did it, thanks for the feedback

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Intellisense takes forever to load, on the theninclude() statement.  but, it will eventually compile if you try a theninclude() on a many to many relationship, so it does actually work.

Comment: As far as it works, if you do this too many times with N:N relationships, the SQL will produce a lot of "CROSS APPLY" returning more data throughput than it should.

Comment: This IntelliSense hiccup was really driving me crazy, until I also tried to just write it down as it should be, and voilá, it builds without problems lol. It was misleading because you can see the overload but not the suggestions once you start typing, which makes you feel you are only on the IList interface basically